# Link to homepage (index) of store using Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I want to link the logo of my site (in my main header) to the homepage of my store. I could do so by linking to the absolute URL (e.g., https://www.example.com), but that doesn't work when I'm testing on a development server that isn't hooked up to my domain name.

I know that I can link to pages using `<a href="{{ pages.example.url }}">`, where `example` is the page I want to link to. But using `<a href="{{ pages.index.url }}">` doesn't seem to work — I'm assuming because `index` is not actually considered a page.

Is there an easy way to link to my store's homepage using a liquid tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `{{ shop.url }}` as listed on this [variable cheat sheet](http://cheat.markdunkley.com/) and in the [Shopify developer reference](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/shop#shop-url).

> Returns the full URL of a shop.
> http://johns-apparel.com

```
<a href="{{ shop.url }}">Homepage</a>
```

You also have the option of using the secure version `{{ shop.secure_url }}`

> Returns the full URL of a shop prepended by the https protocol.
> https://johns-apparel.com

```
<a href="{{ shop.secure_url }}">Homepage</a>
```

I also found in a quick test that it will also return the preview URL when previewing an unpublished page e.g. `k29ijan0ye0r5g7k-51325174.shopifypreview.com`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, for those curious: Just link to `"/"`. So, a link to the homepage of your site should appear as follows in your header.liquid file:

```
<a href="/">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<a href="/">Link</a>` This doesn't work for multilanguage stores.

I think better solution is: `{{ routes.root_url }}`